# JSON.stringify replacer does not replace values

Tags: javascript, json

Why does the replacer not replace the datetime values? Console output is right.

```
let replacer = (key, value) => {
  // console.log("key", key);
  if (value === null) {
    return '';
  } else {
    if (key === 'datetime') {
      console.log('key', key, value);
      return formatDate(value, 'short', 'de');
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
};

const header = Object.keys(items[0]);
let csv = items.map(row =>
  header.map(fieldName =>
    JSON.stringify(
      row[fieldName],
      replacer(fieldName, row[fieldName])
    )
  ).join(','));
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I feel sorry to tell you that but I couldn't see what was wrong until I properly formatted code. I would recommend using prettier automatically on save, welcome in the future ;)

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)` (pass the function, not a call to it)

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xf8k5c27/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because you provide `replacer(fieldName, row[fieldName])` as a replacer argument, which returns a value. Try to provide it a function (instead of a function call)

Comment: when calling `fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)` I don't have the keys in my replacer

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle or something so illustrate your issue ?

Comment: as a side note, I would recommend you to replace `key === 'datetime'` to `value instanceof Date`